# Polars groupby concat on multiple cols returning a list of unique values

Tags: python, python-polars

Have a polars dataframe with the following data.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"small": ["Apple Inc.", "Baidu Inc.", "Chevron Global", "Chevron Global", "Apple Inc."], "person": [10, 20, 30, 10, 10], "comp_big": ["Apple", "Baidu", "Chevron", "Chevron", "Apple"]})
```

Able to groupby on person, but this returns a dataframe of 2 lists.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("person")
    .agg(
        [pl.col(["small", "comp_big"]).unique()]
    )
)
```

Returns

[image: Groupby Result]

This is close, but want to merge the result between small and comp_big into a single list.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("person")
    .agg(
        [pl.col("small") + "|" + pl.col("comp_big")]
    )
)
```

This combines both into a single list, but I would want to split on the pipe and get the unique values.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
    df
    .groupby("person")
    .agg(
        pl.concat_list("small", "comp_big")
          .flatten()
          .unique()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ person ┆ small                             │
│ ---    ┆ ---                               │
│ i64    ┆ list[str]                         │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 20     ┆ ["Baidu", "Baidu Inc."]           │
│ 30     ┆ ["Chevron", "Chevron Global"]     │
│ 10     ┆ ["Chevron", "Apple Inc.", … "Che… │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this using the following - with_columns + groupby.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(pl.col(["small", "comp_big"])).alias("all_companies")
    )
    .groupby("person")
    .agg(
        pl.col("all_companies").flatten().unique()
    )
)
```

EDIT: Adding from the comments.
Solution.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("person")
    .agg(
        pl.concat_list(pl.col("small", "comp_big"))
        .flatten()
        .unique()
        .alias("companies")
    )
)
```

Comment: You can put the `.concat_list` into the `.groupby`. If you want to show that approach here - I can remove my answer.